# como validar un jtextfield desde mvc que ingrese solo numeros

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, jtextfield, text

Un ejemplo de este es la validación de que un textfield, su longitud sea igual a 4 pero, ¿cómo haría para que al ingresar sean sólo números y sólo letras?

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource().equals(t.getTxtdesc()))
    {  
        String Cade=t.getTxtdesc().getText();
        if(Cade.length()==45)
        { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha superado el limite", "AVISO", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            e.consume();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza Document y Filters.

Mira esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers

Siempre puedes modificar el nombre del filtro y los métodos  (en especial test) para crear tu propio filtro. En este caso te aconsejaría el uso de regular expressions para la detección de una cadena que solo contenga una combinación de números y letras.

Saludos.

David

Comment: cuando se referencia una respuesta de otro usuario, se debe mencionar al usuario también para darle su justo reconocimiento

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar este codigo que adapté para java:

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(KeyEvent evt){
    String cadena;
    char variable;
    char keyAscii;
    int intKeyAscii;

    cadena = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ1234567890" + (char)32;
    keyAscii = evt.getKeyChar();
    intKeyAscii = (int)keyAscii;

    if(intKeyAscii > 26){
        if(cadena.indexOf(keyAscii) == -1){
            evt.setKeyChar((char)0);
        }else{
            evt.setKeyChar(keyAscii);
        }
    }
}
```

Con este código el jTextField sólo aceptará letras y números o cualquier caracter que esté contenido en la variable cadena.

PD: el (char)32 corresponde al caracter de espacio.